# Route URLs from a web client back to the web client

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an ASP.NET Controller, that has a function, that simply returns a ContentResult of a WebClient.

In this case, CNN is my testbed, my WebClient, downloads CNN as a string, into it's content, and returns the result as an ActionResult/ContentResult on a controller.

I'm calling a RenderPartial on this action, to get CNN to display "below" and to the right of my current content, in its own box.

The problem I'm running into, is when you click a link on CNN, it redirects to a "relative" url sometimes, and that relative url, doesn't exist in my localhost, and won't exist on my web server, thus the link fails.

When it does redirect to an absolute url, that's also a problem, as the resulting page "replaces" my .NET shell.

What I need it to do, is take any URLs that are inside that ContentResult I returned, and if any of those URLs are clicked, pass them back to my .NET application, to be downloaded by the WebClient, and rendered back in that shell.

I'm aware I could use an IFRAME to do this instead of WebClient, but an IFRAME is impossible in my case, as its restricted by the public API we're consuming, its restricted/has flaws in the framework that API is servicing, and its blocked on some of our client machines, which we have no control over.

Also, the client machines will be off our network, so I can't use an AJAX load, as that'd be XSS.

One idea that I can think of, is basically to create custom routes, with filters/rules, that look for "CNN" like links, and pass them to my controller, as a parameter; then have my controller render my page, and pass those links to the web client.

This would obviously be a lot of work, and not even really sure where to start with it in the routing engine.

The only other thing I can think of that might work, is checking the validity of the URL, by attempting to see if it points to a valid link. If it doesn't point to a valid link, adding CNN's url prefix to it, and seeing if that is then a valid link. But that seems like a lot of work, for a solution that would be a heavy hit on performance, as checking each link on a page like CNN, could be very costly. Also, since I'd be running each link twice, that'd be a problem where POST operations were required, as it'd essentially run each operation twice, and being that this is a public API I'm consuming off a public framework, I wouldn't have control of the source code to safeguard against that.

Any other suggestions?
Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do easily?

Comment: To put it simply; no, there isn't a easy solution to accomplish what you would like to do. You will have to do work if you wish to reframe an entirely different site's content in such a manner.

Comment: Then the path I was chasing down with doing custom routing is probably my most performant/safe route, huh?

Comment: I actually don't have a good answer for you on that, you say CNN is your testbed but how many other site's content do you intend to display? All will appear as similar relative links and then how do you intend to distinguish the actual intended path? There are some techniques you could apply to attempt to change the URI paths in the scraped content with correct URIs but then you run into the problem of when those URIs should not be replaced (images src, scripts src, styles href, etc). Best of luck but not sure if anyone even has a good path to set you down.

Comment: :( yea, I think I got my work cut out for me here anyway I look at it.

Comment: I **haven't** tried this - old school - if you're parsing the HTML see if injecting [`base`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) does it - if it works it's like doing what you mention in your last paragraph, only simpler...curious to see if it works so if you can post results, please do :)

Comment: That actually solves half of my problem, :)

Comment: The other part of the issue is now, I need those links to go ahead and load in just that controller, lol. that's going to be more complicated